# Weird UITableView section collapse animation bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented a collapsible `UITableView` section and having a problem with the animation of the section headers when the section is collapsing.

You can see the weird animation [In this YouTube video...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIYLVmWWfXQ&feature=youtu.be)

I have recorded this with slow animations on to make the glitch more obvious.

The code for toggling the section is as follows...

```
- (void)toggleCollapsedSection:(NSInteger)section {
    VenueDetailsSection *sectionDetails = self.venue.detailsSections[section - 1];

    // the collapsed bool toggles returning 0 for the numberOfRowsInSection method
    sectionDetails.collapsed = !sectionDetails.isCollapsed;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i=0 ; i<sectionDetails.details.count ; ++i) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    }

    if (sectionDetails.isCollapsed) {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    } else {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Looking at the example app from Apple this is pretty much the same code as theirs except in their app they only allow one section to be expanded at once.

Anyway, does anyone know how I can stop that weird section header animation?

I don't know if this is relevant but I am using a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for the section header which its also what they are doing in the Apple sample app.